# Update data via zapier webhook (no log in task history)

Tags: php, webhooks, polling, zapier

I'm currently developing a polling webhook for one of my client. Everything seem to works well when zapier poll a new data. But when if there is an updated data, there isn't any log of it in task history (no error, no success). The data are not sending through the zap after.

To simplify, 1st data polling by zapier, evrything works well. 2nd data (a little bit diferent) nothing append on zapier (however, the data is correctly sent to zapier).

Where can I find better information about webhook? Did i miss something? Any help would be very appreciated!

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 2):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Zapier performs a process called deduplication ([docs](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/deduplication/)) when polling for data. We dedup on the `id` field (or our best guess on what the `id` is). So, even if your whole item changes, if we've seen that `id` before, we'll ignore it.

For reference, the list of ids we've seen is reset when the zap is turned off.